# Width not reacting as it should

Tags: css, width, responsive

I am starting my first project creating a website and I am getting some problems trying to set the width of a div. Somehow it is not taking 100% of the width available for that element.(i want them to display horizontally with equal space between them)
I can only get the three list item to be one next to the other at the begining(left) of his line

**Thats the html:**

```css
.sort_buttons {display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.sort_btn  {display:inline-block;
                    margin:auto;
                    width:auto }
```

```html
 <ul class="sort_buttons">
         <li class="sort_btn" type="button" name="button">size</li>
         <li class="sort_btn" type="button" name="button">size</li>
         <li class="sort_btn" type="button" name="button">size</li>
      </ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just want the three items to be stacked vertically? Remove `display:inline-block;` from `.sort_btn`. That should do the trick...

Comment: I forgot to mention that i would like to have the <li> positioning themselves on the same line horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the div? Do you mean the `ul` element?

If so, that in fact is 100% width.

If you mean you wish for the `li`'s to be 100%, you simply have to use:

`.sort_btn  {
  list-style: none;
}`

Comment: You are totally right i meant the <ul> tag  (at first i tried with <div> tag instead of the <ul> tag and the <button> tag instead of the <li> tag).  sorry for the confusion. i would like to see my <li> elements placed horizontally on the same line taking all the space left available by the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use `display:inline-block;` use `display:flex` to wrap div(in your case:`sort_buttons`)

```css
.sort_buttons {display:flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.sort_btn  {
                    margin:auto;
                    width:auto }
```

```html
 <ul class="sort_buttons">
         <li class="sort_btn" type="button" name="button">size</li>
         <li class="sort_btn" type="button" name="button">size</li>
         <li class="sort_btn" type="button" name="button">size</li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Thank it is already better,  but still not what i wanted and that's why: by removing the inline-block the three elements are displaying exactly as I wanted but on a new line, while I want them to stay on that same line and taking the space available.

Comment: in new line?? do you use `display:flex;` to `.sort_buttons`??

Comment: Yes i just double checked.

If I use inline-block it places it self on the right line but without spacing between the <li> elements.

if I use flex i get the wanted result but on a new line.

Comment: can you post your full code here:https://jsfiddle.net/316yza8o/ (update and show me the new link)

Comment: Sure no problem, but for some reason in jn fiddle the layout of the website is displayed differently than on my browser.

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: Opera, but also on Chrome it is displayed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Updated to automatically adjust width of `.sort_btn` depending on the space available, and also have `.sort_buttons` fill the available space remaining on a line (i.e. if you wanted to another button or menu).

I think this is what you're aiming for.

```css
.bar {
  display: flex;
}
 
.sort_buttons {
  display:flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.sort_btn  {
  margin:auto;
  width:auto 
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
 
     <div class="title">
         Sort Options:
     </div>
 
     <div class="sort_buttons">
         <div class="sort_btn">size</div>
         <div class="sort_btn">size</div>
         <div class="sort_btn">size</div>
      </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: It does work, but still it takes a new whole line instead of putting itself next to other elements on a already existing line.

Comment: It's not adding a new line, but there was the default margin around the `<ul>` class that I have now removed. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Updated again, I think you want the buttons to fill the remaining space in a full width `div` with other content that already exists...